# Opencv works with raspberry pi locally but not thru network

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I have the basic python program running on my raspberry pi. It works with no issues. But I was trying to log in to the pi thru another computer like SSH and run the same python program it gives me errors like the video isn't working. What am I doing wrong. Do I need to force the RPI to use its monitor to get this work or what? Any suggestions?

I get this error:

Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(Video:1363): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

This is my program:

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
import cv2

# initialize the camera and grab a reference to the raw camera capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 32
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

# allow the camera to warmup
time.sleep(0.1)

# capture frames from the camera
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    # grab the raw NumPy array representing the image, then initialize the timestamp
    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    image = frame.array 
    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF 
    # clear the stream in preparation for the next frame
    rawCapture.truncate(0) 
    # if the `q` key was pressed, break from the loop
    if key == ord("q"):
       break
```

Answer (score 4):

`export DISPLAY=:0`  and then run your code.
If you run it without above code, it will run it in the current shell. In simple words, when you export display, you are connecting to a current instance of running raspberry session, and it will act like you are running it locally.
`NOTE` In some cases, you need to `export DISPLAY=:0.0`. Just google it for your os.

Comment: Another note, if you connect wit the `ssh -X username@host` it will redirect the session to your local pc and you'll see the output directly from your pc rather than raspberry.